# R: put results of function in corresponding original position of inputs after a subset

Tags: r

Suppose I have two matrices `mat` and `obj`:

```
time <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
money <- c(2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6)
ownership <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
randomstuff <- matrix(runif(18),nrow = 3)
mat <- rbind(time, money, ownership, randomstuff)

dat <- c(1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0)  
obj <- matrix(dat,nrow=1)
```

I am running them through a function:

```
f <- function(mat,obj){fake function outputting a vector the same length as obj}

soln <- f(mat, obj).
```

where `soln` is a 1x6 matrix.

How could I transform (elegantly - this is actually a 70000+ column matrix) the matrices `mat` and `obj` to:

```
time <- c(1, 2, 3)
money <- c(2, 4, 6)
ownership <- c(1, 1, 1)
mat <- rbind(time, money, ownership, randomstuff) 

dat <- list(1, 2, 3)  
obj <- matrix(dat,nrow=1)
```

with the `soln` being a 1x3 matrix.

```
soln=          [,1]     [,2]      [,3]     
       [1,] 4.151969 5.759826  5.537563
```

where the decision to exclude a column from `mat` is based on the value in `ownership[]=0` and the same for `obj`.  The added difficulty, is that I need to be able to assign the output in `soln` to the mapped to the corresponding original position in a larger `SOLN` matrix.  In this case columns 1,3,5.  Ownership is randomly assigned, so there will be no pattern other than the zeros described above.

The suggestion to use:

```
obj2 <- obj[, as.logical(ownership), drop = FALSE]
mat2 <- mat[, as.logical(ownership)]
```

works perfectly for that piece.  How do I put the `soln` values in positions 1,3,5 of a larger `SOLN` matrix? The `SOLN` matrix below is an example of possible output.  In this case, I want columns 1, 3, and 5 to be filled by this function.  Subsequent operations (same operation different `ownership`) will fill columns 2, 4 and 6.

```
SOLN =          [,1]    [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]
       [1,] 4.151969 1.08251 5.759826 3.368613 5.537563 3.471643
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `mat[, as.logical(ownership)] ; obj[, as.logical(ownership), drop = FALSE]` ?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thank you! This certainly gets me to the subset piece.  It's the mapping back that still has me now.  I will edit the question.

Comment: I am very confused what the `SOLN` matrix should look like.  Could you please give an example output that you want at the end?

Comment: @Barker Thank you, yes I will edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial answer.  I can find the column index:

```
soln2 <- c(7,8,9)

index <- which(ownership==1, arr.ind=TRUE)
> index
[1] 1 3 5
```

Now, I know that I need to create a result space:

```
SOLN <- matrix(data=NA,nrow=1,ncol=6)
> SOLN
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA

> SOLN[,1]<-soln2[1]
> SOLN[,3]<-soln2[2]
> SOLN[,5]<-soln2[3]
> SOLN
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    7   NA    8   NA    9   NA
```

I need a way to do this over 70,000 times.  There is probably an `APPLY` function I should use, but I do not know what it is.  I do have a for loop solution.

```
> for (i in 1:length(index)){
+   j=index[[i]]
+   print(j)
+   SOLN[,j]=soln2[i]
+  }
[1] 1
[1] 3
[1] 5
> SOLN
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    7   NA    8   NA    9   NA
```

Any suggestions for a more elegant solution would be appreciated!

Comment: I have no idea what `SOLN` or `soln2` are, how they are being generated and what on earth are you trying to with then. Your question is beyond confusing. And if you want to fill `SOLN` with `soln2` you could just do `SOLN[, as.logical(ownership)] <- soln2` so not sure what are you trying to do with that `for` loop there